# Show sorted predicates in Clingo

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

I have a predicate `pred/2`, how do I `#show` this predicate in the answer that is sorted by the first argument, given that the first argument will be numerical?

I couldn't find any relevant documentation on how Clingo orders its output predicates.

Comment: Please add a minimal example

Answer (score 0):

The clingo system allows you to solve exponentially hard problems. It has no sophisticated options to sort the output. Use the clingo python API or a postprocessor to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use case... you can encourage the discovered answer sets to be sorted (and adjacent) if you structure its choices:

```
% Equivalent to: { pred(N) : N=1..100 }.
{ pred(1) }.
{ pred(N+1) } :- pred(N), N < 100.
```

Now the answer sets containing `pred(_)` will always start at 1 and be sequential, and will be sorted in the output.

In my brief experiments, the drawback was ~3% increase in solution time.